# Find if a random variable is a proxy variable using neural networks

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-variables, neural-networks, causality

I have a probabilistic graphical model (a toy example):

[image]

where $B$ is a proxy variable to $A$.

I would like to understand: is $B$ a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(statistics)) to $A$?

My idea is to train a neural network with a single neuron in the input and output layer. And if it will be able to convert the random variable into $A$ into $B$, then I can conclude that B is the proxy to A.

Also, does somebody know where I can read more about similar problems (books, papers)...

Comment: "approximate a connection" is unclear.

Comment: @David thank you for pointing on that, what I need basically is $p(B|A)$ (I hope it's correct), since it's a probabilistic graphical model.

Comment: This is much too vague. It uses a number of buzzwords but actually says very little. You'll have to be much more specific if you want real answers.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson thank you for the advice, would you be so kind as to point which part you do not understand most?

Comment: @Paddy I find it hard to say. I don't mean to be overly harsh, but there's just no meat to any of it. I suppose the biggest thing that would help would be if you had specific random variables you were interested in. As it is, your post is a slightly higher-level version of, "Given two expressions, how do I solve them?", which is similarly too vague to have any real answer.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson, you're not harsh at all. I have completely rewritten my question, hope it will be more clear now.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for? In my opinion a proxy $B$ is good if it has all information about $A$ that's important to determine $C$. So the question would be $P(C|A,B)=P(C|B)$? But that's what your graphical model says. So by definition (your graphical model) the answer is yes? Isn't it rather that you want to know if the graphical model is valid?

Comment: @Its_me exactly, I would like to prove that my model is valid using NNs. It's just for an illustration; in real life, it can be that $A$ has no influence on $B$.

Comment: The general context of the problem is clear, but the specific question should be better clarified. Surely a neural network based on your graphical model could be built. And surely, with an adequate network architecture and learning process, it could take the information of $A$ and move it into the variable $B$, creating a valid proxy of $A$ from which to obtain the output $C$. However, adding details to your question could probably facilitate more targeted comments and answers.

Comment: @Anatoly, thank you for your points. I'm just looking for a justification, that my idea (mathematically) makes sense. I will think how can I extend my question...

Comment: Well, I haven't understood whether my answer is acceptable or not.... would you mind telling me if my thought was right ?

Comment: But yes ! There is something ! As long as A is independent of other factors (influences, I mean), B can be proxy to A , can't it be ? Since A is proxy to B, and that A is independent of other influences, an increase or a decrease in B may necessarily mean an increase or a decrease in A !